# How to install Java JRE on FreeBSD with as few dependencies as possible

Tags: freebsd, java, nix

I've been trying to get Java working on my FreeBSD 7.1 server. I just want the runtime, since the JDK drags all kinds of unnecessary dependencies with it, and I just need it to run a jar file periodically. I've installed the FreeBSD-supported [diablo-jre](http://www.freshports.org/java/diablo-jre16/), but whenever I try to run it, I get a:

```
/usr/local/diablo-jre1.6.0/bin/java: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

So what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I've figured it out. For all this time, I've been trying to run the amd64 version on a machine that's still running i386. Mea culpa.

So to install Java on your FreeBSD server with as few depedencies as possible:

- Download the tarball (make sure to pick the one under the tarballs header, and for the correct FreeBSD version and platform) from [The FreeBSD foundation's Java downloads](http://www.freebsdfoundation.org/downloads/java.shtml).
- Put the downloaded file in `/usr/ports/distfiles/`
- `# cd /usr/ports/java/diablo-jre16`
- `# make config install clean`
- Be sure to disable all optional components from the configuration screen.
- Let the installation run its course and be happy :)

Comment: Wow, and the prize of worse error message goes too ... FreeBSD!

Answer (score 1):

```
file /usr/local/diablo-jre1.6.0/bin/java
```

Will probably tell you that java is actually a shell script that sets up an environment and launches the real JRE

Comment: Yeah. Could be wrong shell messing up the script

Comment: It does not appear to be so – the command returns:


/usr/local/diablo-jre1.6.0/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (FreeBSD), for FreeBSD 7.0 (700055), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), FreeBSD-style, not stripped

Comment: Weird, try strace'ing it (or the FreeBSD alternative, truss ?)

Comment: Ok, I've tried with truss (no strace) and it gives this result:
http://dpaste.com/hold/41024/ – I'm not a real expert into such things, but it looks like there's something completely wrong with the Java binary.

Answer (score 0):

I used the last JRE version for Windows, installed in my home directiry under .wine. Then I run `java -jar program_name.jar` from command line in a shell, and it's OK.

Program runs perfectly for me.