# What's the diablo-jre? (FreeBSD)

Tags: java, freebsd

This link mentions about diablo-jre.

[How to install Java JRE on FreeBSD with as few dependencies as possible](https://serverfault.com/questions/1077/how-to-install-java-jre-on-freebsd-with-as-few-dependencies-as-possible)

What's that and why should I use it instead of other implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Diablo JRE is the prebuilt Java Runtime Environment (commonly know as "Java Software" for your computer). Sun/Oracle doesn't make a version that is natively compatible with FreeBSD, but has licensed the FreeBSD Foundation to distribute a copy (normally you can not distribute a prebuilt copy of the JRE unless Sun/Oracle made it).

You can get the various versions from the [FreeBSD Foundation Java Website](http://www.freebsdfoundation.org/downloads/java.shtml).

They make installing the JRE or JDK quick and simple. Diablo is a reference to Beastie (which can't be cobranded for licensing reasons).